# Getting 401 Unauthorized error even after sending correct credentials in Basic Authentication header of RestTemplate

Tags: resttemplate

Following is the wrapper API code that is being fired :-

```
logger.info("Inside Method");
    String integrationUrl=null;
    String integrationUsername = null;
    String integrationPassword = null;
    
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(System.getenv("PushGDSDataUrl")))
            integrationUrl = System.getenv("PushGDSDataUrl");
        else
            integrationUrl = "https://test.connect.boomi.com/ws/simple/createCommentsx-test";
        
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(System.getenv("PushGDSDataUrlUsername")))
            integrationUsername = System.getenv("PushGDSDataUrlUsername");
        else
            integrationUsername = "<integration-username>";
                                   
        
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(System.getenv("PushGDSDataUrlPwd")))
            integrationPassword = System.getenv("PushGDSDataUrlPwd");
        else
            integrationPassword = "<integration-password>";
                                   
    
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
   // headers.set("dcuid", integrationUsername);
    //headers.set("dcpwd", integrationPassword);
  //  headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
    
    String auth = integrationUsername + ":" + integrationPassword;
    byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64( 
       auth.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")) );
    String authHeader = "Basic " + new String( encodedAuth );
    headers.set( "Authorization", authHeader );
   // headers.set("Body","{\r\n\"class_name\":\"Server\",\r\n\"company_name:\"ABC\"\r\n}\r\n");
    
    
    GDSPushData newObj = new GDSPushData();
    newObj.setClass_name(className);
    newObj.setCompany_name(companyName);
    
    String jsonInString = new Gson().toJson(newObj);
    JSONObject mJSONObject = new JSONObject(jsonInString);
    logger.info("Request is set");
    
    



    HttpEntity<String> entityReq = new HttpEntity<String>(mJSONObject.toString(),headers);
    
    logger.info("Request is converted");
    
    
        
         URI targetUrl = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(integrationUrl).build().encode().toUri(); //Build base url
            
            
            logger.info("target Url"+targetUrl);
            
          
            
            ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(integrationUrl, HttpMethod.POST, entityReq, String.class);
            
            //String result = restTemplate.getForObject(targetUrl, String.class);



            logger.info(result.getStatusCodeValue());
            logger.info(result.getBody());
```

When we are firing the intergation url mentioned in above code using postman after specifying same credentials, then it is working fine and we are getting 200 OK response code and when same code is being fired from Spring Java application then we are getting 401 unauthorized error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try using the following code

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("<Your_URL>");

 List<NameValuePair> arguments = new ArrayList<>();
arguments.add(new BasicNameValuePair("class_name", className));
arguments.add(new BasicNameValuePair("company_name", companyName));

 try{
String auth = integrationUsername + ":" + integrationPassword;
byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(
auth.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")) );
String authHeader = "Basic " + new String( encodedAuth );

post.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
post.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/json");
post.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,authHeader);
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(arguments));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```